How to group by and concatenate strings but skip one group?
I have a table with people and the groups they belong to. It is formatted like so:
person_id <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "B1", "B1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2")
year <- c(2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016)
group_id <- c("abc", "abc", "cdz", "cdz", "abc", "abc", "ghe", "ghe", "abc", "fjx", "ghe", "ghe", "cdz", "cdz")
example <- data.frame(person_id, group_id, year)

I want to create a column that for each person shows which other people they share a group with in a particular year. This is what I have currently:
example <- within(example, {
  connections <- ave(person_id, group_id, year, 
                     FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse=', ')
                     )})
res <- example %>%
  group_by(person_id, year) %>%
  summarise(joint=paste(connections, collapse=', '))

This is close to what I need, but I do not want to include the person_id in each row. For example, my code creates a new column with the first value of "A1,A2,B1,A1,C2". I would like have this value be "A2,B1,C2". In my example person B1 does not share a group with anyone in 2016. My code produces the row value of "B1", but I would like this cell to be an empty string. How can I achieve this?
Also, the data I am working with is quite large, approximately 1 billion rows. It seems rather inefficient to group by twice, but I am not sure what I want to do is possible without doing so. Is there a better way to approach this?
Note: I cannot use tidyr. Also, my R version is 3.4.3.

I don't understand why C1 appears in the first row. C1 does not share a group with A1 in 2015 or in 2016, so why does it show up in the first row of the result?

@GregorThomas My bad, just a typo.

code without tidyr:
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

example %>%
  mutate(p_y = paste(person_id, year, sep = '_'), person_id =NULL, year = NULL) %>%
  igraph::graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  igraph::components() %>%
  igraph::membership() %>%
  enframe() %>%
  filter(grepl('_', name)) %>%
  mutate(person_id = sub("_.*", "", name), year = sub(".*_", "", name))%>%
  group_by(year, value) %>%
  mutate(value = list(person_id)) %>%
  group_by(person_id, year) %>%
  summarise(value = toString(setdiff(value[[1]], person_id)), .groups = 'drop')


   # A tibble: 12 × 3
   person_id year  value       
   <chr>     <chr> <chr>       
 1 A1        2015  "A2, B1, C2"
 2 A1        2016  "A2, C2"    
 3 A2        2015  "A1, B1, C2"
 4 A2        2016  "A1, C2"    
 5 A3        2015  "C1"        
 6 A3        2016  "C1"        
 7 B1        2015  "A1, A2, C2"
 8 B1        2016  ""          
 9 C1        2015  "A3"        
10 C1        2016  "A3"        
11 C2        2015  "A1, A2, B1"
12 C2        2016  "A1, A2" 


Edit:
In the case where no transitivity:
example %>%
  group_by(year, group_id) %>%
  mutate(v = list(person_id)) %>%
  group_by(person_id, year) %>%
  summarise(v = toString(setdiff(unlist(v), person_id)))
  
# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   person_id [6]
   person_id  year v           
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       
 1 A1         2015 "A2, B1, C2"
 2 A1         2016 "A2, C2"    
 3 A2         2015 "A1, B1"    
 4 A2         2016 "A1"        
 5 A3         2015 "C1"        
 6 A3         2016 "C1"        
 7 B1         2015 "A1, A2"    
 8 B1         2016 ""          
 9 C1         2015 "A3"        
10 C1         2016 "A3"        
11 C2         2015 "A1"        
12 C2         2016 "A1"  


I receive "Error: Column 'year' must be length 1 (a summary value), not 14." I think this is because my R version is 3.4.3. Is this approach still possible in my R version (I cannot update R on my machine)? Also, in your results the year is 2015 for every row. How can I have the correct year for each person?

Unfortunately, I do not have tidyr on my machine. I also do not have permission to install new packages. So I cannot use unite. And where does p_y come from?

@sla813 p_y is a new variable. You can simply use mutate(p_y = paste(person_id, year, sep = '_'), person_id =NULL, year = NULL) instead of unite

@sla813 do you have igraph? Thats the backbone of the code. The rest can be done using base R. Let me know if you have igraph.

I do have igraph.

Can this be done without separate? It is also from tidyr.

@sla813 yes. change separate to mutate(person_id = sub("_.*", "", name), year = sub(".*_", "", name))

Now I get "Error: Column 'value' can't be modified because it's a grouping variable."

@sla813 seems the old R did not allow the grouping variable to be modified. Change the mutate(value = ...) into mutate(val= list(person_id)) then in summarize use val[[1]] instead of value[[1]]

One issue persists. Rows 2, 4, 12 for column value should not contain "B1" because B1 is in a group by itself in 2016.

@sla813 thats an oversight. its supposed to be group_by(year, value) in the first grouping instead of group_by(value) alone

Apologies, one more thing. Since C2 is only in a group with A1, rows 3,4,7 should not contain "C2" and rows 11, 12 should only be "A1".

@sla813 C2 is in a group with A1 and A1 is in a group with A2. so by transitivity, A2 and C2 are in a group. Unless you only consider one edge and not all edges in which case, we will not use igraph. This was not well presented in your original question

aggregate by group_id with toString, merge to original, aggregate again by person_id, then strsplit on ", ", setdiff, make data.frame and merge to original.
> example |> 
+   merge(aggregate(cbind(pid=person_id) ~ group_id + year, example, toString)) |> 
+   aggregate(pid ~ person_id, toString) |> 
+   {\(.) Map(\(x, y) setdiff(unique(x), y), strsplit(.$pid, ', '), .$person_id) |> 
+       list() |> 
+       list2DF() |> 
+       data.frame(person_id=.$person_id, pid=_)}() |> 
+   merge(example)
   person_id      Var.2 group_id year
1         A1 A2, B1, C2      abc 2015
2         A1 A2, B1, C2      abc 2016
3         A1 A2, B1, C2      cdz 2015
4         A1 A2, B1, C2      cdz 2016
5         A2     A1, B1      abc 2015
6         A2     A1, B1      abc 2016
7         A3         C1      ghe 2015
8         A3         C1      ghe 2016
9         B1     A1, A2      abc 2015
10        B1     A1, A2      fjx 2016
11        C1         A3      ghe 2015
12        C1         A3      ghe 2016
13        C2         A1      cdz 2015
14        C2         A1      cdz 2016


Data:
> dput(example)
structure(list(person_id = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
"A3", "A3", "B1", "B1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2"), group_id = c("abc", 
"abc", "cdz", "cdz", "abc", "abc", "ghe", "ghe", "abc", "fjx", 
"ghe", "ghe", "cdz", "cdz"), year = c(2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 
2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

